# Error loading uploaded API data into template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a service that returns me the user's data according to the Token stored in the localStorage and everything is returned correctly until I get to my component.

The real problem is that I have the following code in my component.ts file:
[image]

Apparently, at least everything should work out for me. However, in the console it is possible to notice that even after I have assigned the return to my user property it is printed as undefined. As shown in the image below.
[image]

When trying to use in the HTML template I get messages saying that it was not possible to load data from the user property. I have already tried using async pipe like this: (user $ | async) as user. I tried to use the safe navigation like this:user?.email.

But it did nothing and I have no idea why this happens. Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Please add the code for the clientHeaderService and your HTML. In any case your console.log() is done outside the subscribe method, so it won't work. Add this.clientHeaderService.getUser().subscribe(response => {this.user = response; console.log(this.user);}). Also the async pipe is to be used with observables, your user variable is not an observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User$ represents a stream, should be assigned this way：

```
export class {
    // a stream type
    user$: Obserable<User>;

    ngOnInit() {
        // a stream type
        this.user$ = this.clienteHeaderService.getUser();
    }

}
```

and the template add `|async` pipe.

Answer (score 0):

`this.user` is not immediately available after you call `subscribe()`, it is very possible that the `getUser()` hasn't emitted any result by the time `console.log(this.user)` is called.

If you just wanted to see what's in `this.user`, you may try it in the callback of `subscribe()`

```
this.clientHeaderService.getUser().subscribe((response) => {
  this.user = response;
  console.log(this.user); // this.user should be available here
})
```

On the template side, you should be able to just access the user via `{{ user }}`.

I'd also suggest to use share your minimum reproducible code at https://stackblitz.com/, to get help more easily.

Comment: I'm just logging into the console to be able to preview the data beforehand, because the intention is to actually display them in the HTML template. The problem is that in the template it does not matter what form I use, it always gives error loading anything from user.

Comment: `this.user` will not have any values until the `getUser()` actually emits any result, that's why it is undefined. You should show your HTML template too, or just use stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe almost work like promise in javascript and it has a callback

```
.subscribe(response=>this.user=response)
```

Callback are pushed to the end of current event loop .So you are accessing

```
console.log(this.user)
```

before callback in your subscribe get executed.

instead
  try

```
.subscribe((response) => {
  this.user=response;
  //you can access value of this.user here or call other function here to 
  //access this.user
  console.log(this.user);

})
```